# How to establish a direct peer-peer connection between two computers in two distant locations through internet?

Tags: networking, server, client, ngrok, post-processing

While building an application by python for implementing post-processing in Quantum Key Distribution, I require a server (say Alice) and a client(say Bob) at distant locations to interact and exchange some information while doing the required calculations simultaneously (for which threading is used).
At first, the open-source NGROK service was used as a hosting server but it makes the time required for post-processing very huge mainly due to network congestion.
So, is there a way to establish a direct peer-to-peer connection between Alice and Bob via the internet wherein Alice's system itself acts as a server thereby bypassing a third-party host server? If there is a way out please suggest one otherwise any leads or suggestions for open source services better than NGROK would be highly helpful.

PS: If you need any additional information for providing help, i would be eager to respond.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: This question is very broad and likely already answered. The simple answer is yes. The complex answer is it depends on the connection of alice to the internet. There are firewalls and nat routers, that need configuration to enable incoming connection requests to a server.